# Multiple Where Clause in Single Table Select Query

Tags: sql

hi friends i have a table with amount and tax as follow

table1

```
Amount        tax
200            5
300            2
100           12
 50            5
200           12
```

in the above table i have `amount` column and `tax`, here i want the total sum of amount where with `tax` clause

example like  `sum(amount) where tax='2'` , `sum(amount) where tax='5'`,and `sum(amount) where tax='12'`

and i want output like

```
    amount_2 | tax_2 | amount_5 | tax_5 | amount_12 | tax_12
----------------------------------------------------------
    300      |  2    | 250      |  5    |   300     | 12
```

Comment: Is it OK to assume that the tax rates are only `2`, `5` or `12`, or does it need to be more generic than that?

Comment: i have only 5 different taxes like 0, 5, 12, 18, 28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something as below for conditional sum

```
select 
sum(case when tax = 2 then amount else 0 end) amount_2,
2 as tax_2,
sum(case when tax = 5 then amount else 0 end) amount_5,
5 as tax_5,
sum(case when tax = 12 then amount else 0 end) amount_12,
12 as tax_12
from table
 /* group by somecol if needed sum per group*/
```

Comment: Could also use `else null` (or omit the `else 0`) for the same effect... other than if the tax had no rows the sum would be null. Not really important in this case, but if they wanted the average instead it would be required. Just 2 cents no one asked for. ;)

Comment: @Uueerdo i agree